# Is a question about Jewish book resources appropriate for this site?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

There is a very popular question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books) that I think would be good to ask on judaism.SE. The issue is as stated on stackoverflow that this type of question strictly speaking should not be on a SE site.

what would the appropriate way (if any) to ask this question?

To clarify what I want to ask is something of the sort: "What are the best resources for Jewish texts on the internet?" OR "What websites should every Jew have bookmarked?"

Comment: Good question. It looks like the community is taking some time to think about it. I know I am. Here are some past questions of a similar form: [Starting a Library](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/347/starting-a-jewish-library), [Divrei Torah Site](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4041/best-site-for-reading-listening-to-great-divrei-torah), [Hebrew Blog](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3914/what-is-the-best-jewish-blog-about-the-modern-hebrew-language), [Books on Prayer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5810/books-on-tefillah)

Comment: @IsaacMoses, and a new one: ["Essential Jewish Websites"](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7964).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAICT the reason such questions are frowned upon on SE sites is that they're subjective, with no answer objectively better than any other. Asking such a question on Judaism.SE and asking not what "what do you recommend" but "what does Judaism recommend, and can you cite a source for it" would work, I think. That setup doesn't work for all questions of this sort, but would for, e.g., ["Starting a Jewish Library"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/347).

(Personally, I don't see why a seeking-a-bunch-of-subjective-responses question is bad, but if SE says so, then, well, we've gotta play by the rules.)

Comment: How much good do these lists of links do, especially without any prose explaining the value of each link?

Comment: Well, if you cite sources (as mentioned in my answer here), that's as good as prose explaining value, I think. Or are you referring to my last sentence, "I don't see why..."? That was just thrown into my answer as a little bit of soapboxing. I don't think this question (or [site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)) is the right forum to discuss it really....